# text-transform:uppercase bug in Google Chrome v.22

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I've come across a bug (since last week) in Chrome (Version 22.0.1229.79) with some javascript that is attempting to convert a field value to uppercase.  It seems to be conflicting with CSS (text-transform:uppercase) that is making the field value *look* uppercase at the same time.
When tabbing out of the field, the onChange event handler will attempt to change the field value into uppercase, but the result is that the field becomes empty.  But if you try typing into the field again, your previous text reappears.

Has anyone else seen the same thing?  I think it needs reporting to Google.

Here is a test case for it... http://jsfiddle.net/fhBx2/2/

```
<script>
function upperKey(obj) 
{
    var val = obj.value;
    if(val != null)
    {
        obj.value = val.toUpperCase();
    }    
}
</script>

<input type="text" style="text-transform:uppercase;" 
onchange="upperKey(this);"/>
```

Comment: Nice catch! maybe if you report it you could get some money from google:  http://blog.chromium.org/2010/01/encouraging-more-chromium-security.html

Comment: @Perroloco Where's the security problem here? You'd better point the OP to the bug reporting site: http://new.crbug.com/

Comment: weird; the value comes back if you resume typing into the field after it has been "cleared"

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it could be classed as a security issue, unfortunately for me.
It's fine if you initially type in capital letters or numbers

Comment: Logged: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=153258

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone who actually has an issue with this, I've found that you can do a workaround by resetting the value to blank and then back to the original value, but uppercased.

```
$(function() {
    $('input').change(function(e) {
        var val = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
        $(this).val('').val(val);
    });
});​
```

See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JXA8K/2/

Comment: waste of resources, just bind your CSS rule to <option> tag